# BigQuery not doing table pruning

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset come into BigQuery with a JSON field which has a ton of data in it. I've created scheduled queries which create some 22 normalized tables which link together on an ID field.

If I build a Tableau data model on top of those 22 tables, it works just great.

However if I create a BigQuery view on top of those 22 tables, I can't do a simple query. Even if the query only selects data from 3 of the tables, the explain plan goes crazy and accesses every table.

I do have a solution to the problem, which is to put the query layer in Tableau, but I dislike putting the semantic layer in the visualization layer - it is inelegant.

I feel like I must be missing something fundamental in how BigQuery works?

For example, the following simple query runs fine, as you would expect:

SELECT
customer,
release,
COUNT(releaseCount)
FROM
activations
JOIN customer ON activations.id1=customer.id1
JOIN release ON activations.id2=release.id2
GROUP BY customer, release

But the same query:

SELECT
customer,
release,
COUNT(releaseCount)
FROM
`project.view`
GROUP BY customer, release

Fails spectacularly with an incredibly complicated explain plan. If I remove the tables that I don't need for that specific query from the master query, the problem of course goes away, but I want to retain all tables in the master query so I can select the data I want when I want it in the visualization layer (Tableau or Looker Studio).